# Creating functions in a hierarchy where they get the same arguments

Tags: functional-programming, typescript

When I write code, I tend to follow functional paradigms often. The main thing I try to do is use values returned from functions.

What I notice though, is I end up having a sort of function argument funnel where all the functions in the chain have the same arguments.

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

function dbFilePath(dbFilename: string) {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../", dbFilename + ".db")
  return filePath
}

export function fileData(dbFilename: string) {
  const file = dbFilePath(dbFilename)

  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(
    file,
    "utf-8"
  );

  return fileContent
}
```

In this example code (which works fine), both functions have the same argument. This is an example of what I normally do.

What is best practice for structuring this piece of code?

Comment: Is the piece of code you posted something you'd actually used or heavily simplified?

Comment: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915).

Comment: @Mast - this came directly from my source code. As it says, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function type which will accept only 1 parameter like this

```
type AccpetString<T> = (s: string) => T;
```

Then you need to save your functions in variables with type `AccpetString<T>` like this:

```
const dbFilePath:AccpetString<string> = dbFilename => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../', dbFilename + '.db');

  return filePath;
}
```

or like this:

```
export const fileData:AccpetString<string> = function(dbFilename) {
  const file = dbFilePath(dbFilename);

  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(
    file,
    'utf-8'
  );

  return fileContent
}
```

Now you don't need to specify the type of `dbFilename` in your functions

If your functions returns the `string` always, then we can declare a new type like this

```
type AccpetStringReturnString = AccpetString<string>
```

and rewrite your functions like this:

```
const dbFilePath:AccpetStringReturnString = dbFilename => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../', dbFilename + '.db');

  return filePath;
}
```

or like this:

```
export const fileData:AccpetStringReturnString = function(dbFilename) {
  const file = dbFilePath(dbFilename);

  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(
    file,
    'utf-8'
  );

  return fileContent
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAMwM6KhEcDkzMG4CwAUKJLHGAIYwAWq6WlNeRRMAnmAKZwCCAxny4wAyjCjAAdgHMAPABUAfHAC8cABRIAXHCRjJUgJQqlcgoXZdeAoaPHSASpxgBXKBNv6VVwU4-SZunZSCmZEfBASunAAJgBGAGLAADacAApU1Jr8PiJ6-oH6SqpxiSkSFCDcykoA3kRwcOGR8AjJaRlejNQAdABWEJJqAPpD0cBuFZwANFjd3QD0mDMlbeWVcADUs3GYBqGEDVBOrhKIbek0ZgC+LIScAB6k8E1RrSkAIlQUWda+eVKOFxuPxSLwIZwSPgwYARNQrMqTIx1A6NCKvNpeeHtGhwhKrRH7BovFptADCERgnAk8FUyG6Rwo0VKnGEbEhanqDTOKSmnIamGcMAQAFoAByYTl7W6HY5ubmccnUqkwIhXIA)